# Error 500 Upload image to strapi with Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, strapi

I need to upload image to Strapi. I have a table named book, and with three fields: b_type, b_num, b_image. However, the status code is 500, but without pushing b_image it is 200.

```java
let file
    const ImageUpload = () =>{
        let box = document.querySelector('.popup_win')
        let uploadField = document.querySelector('.upload')
        uploadField.addEventListener('change', (e) =>{
            file = e.currentTarget.files[0]
            checkType(file)
        })
     }
const finish = ()=>{
        const form = new FormData()
        form.append('b_image', file)
        form.append('b_num', 3)
        form.append('b_type', 'student')

        axios.post('http://localhost:1337/books', form, {
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
        })
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data)

        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e)
        })
        document.querySelector('.popup').style.display='none'
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the documentation about the file upload it can help you https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/guides/upload.html#file-upload.

So first you have to create your `Book` entry without your image.

And then you have to upload your files and set the entry you want to link.

So it will be 2 request for that.

Here is an example https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/guides/upload.html#examples
We link an image to an existing article.

Comment: The example doesn't do two requests and there is an option to create when entry is made: https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/plugins/upload.html#examples-2 THANKS FOR STRAPI BTW!

Answer (score 1):

Took a while to work out but here's how I did it:

```
const submitUpload = e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const formData = new FormData(e.target);

  axios.post("http://localhost:1337/images", {})
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res);

      formData.append('refId', res.data.id);

      axios.post(`http://localhost:1337/upload`, formData, {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
      })
        .then(res => {
          console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

return (
  <form id='form' onSubmit={e => submitUpload(e)}>
    <input type="file" name="files" />
    <input type="text" name="ref" value="image" />
    <input type="text" name="field" value="image" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
)
```

The `ref` and `refId` input values' meanings are given here https://strapi.io/documentation/3.x.x/guides/upload.html#examples.